# Improving "How to Ask" sidebar?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, asking-questions

I particularly enjoyed the Google Webmaster Central blog entry [Tips for getting help with your site](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/tips-for-getting-help-with-your-site.html).

It covers how to ask questions in a public forum rather well, and I think almost all the rules apply to our Q&A engine:

1. Ask in public.
2. Do your homework.
3. Be specific.
4. Make it relevant to others.
5. Let us know if you’ve found a bug.
6. Stay on-topic.
7. Stay calm.
8. Listen, even when it’s not what you wanted to hear.

I think the only one that isn't relevant (except on meta) is #5 and *possibly* #7.

As for all the others, I believe we've discussed them in some detail here on meta, and I was wondering if we could somehow incorporate this advice, maybe in the "how to ask" sidebar?

[image]

Comment: and there is also Jon's take on this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx and the latest:  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I like this list better than what's on the how to ask section of the stackoverflow faq (which is about bicycles and not programming).

Answer (score 6):

The way you've bolded "Is your question about programming" makes it seem that this sidebar is more about what's on-topic.

I would suggest the following

> #### Asking Good Questions
>
> Good questions are more likely to get good answers.
>
> - Be specific
> - Stay on-topic
> - Do your homework
> - Make it relevant to others
> - Listen, even when it’s not what you wanted to hear
>
> [faq link, just like you already have it]

I would make "Asking Good Questions" a link to a more detailed page.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've already linked to my [(excessively?) detailed article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)... so how about including some form of my golden rule: read the question you've just written, and see whether it's the kind of question *you'd* want to answer.

In case I haven't made it clear elsewhere, btw, you're very welcome to take that blog post and adapt / expand / trim it as much as you like, and post it wherever you want.

Comment: By the way, doesn't [rubber ducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) apply to asking good questions, too? I.e. what about "read the question you've just written (aloud), ..."?

Comment: @Tobias: I'm not sure it needs to be aloud, but it's basically the same idea, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is now completed as

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/